# Create a compact, non-SOAP web service in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, web-config, ihttphandler

I want to create a simple web service to distribute to ASP.Net developers. I found an application ([SvnBridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/)) which has the layout I'm after - a single `web.config` file and a single `.dll` file.

The interesting part is in the `web.config` file:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <clear/>
    <add verb="*" path="*" type="SvnBridgeServer.SvnBridgeHttpHandler, SvnBridgeServer" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Ooooo that looks perfect. I can throw anything I like at this and have it handled by what I presume is an `IHttpHandler` implementation.

So I ripped off the spirit of the afore-linked config file, bundled my library into a DLL and hit *build* in VS. I immediately get this in IE:

> **Source Error:**
>
> [No relevant source lines]

I mainly work with PHP - ASP.Net is quite new to me. Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I haven't a clue where even to start.

At the moment, I use a Python script to bundle all the C# source into a single `.ashx` file, which is kinda cool for distribution, but makes debugging a nightmare. It looks a bit like this:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="MyApp.MyClass" debug="true" %>
using System.Data;
...
namespace MyApp
{
    public class MyClass : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext Http)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

There's obviously a lot more to it (user config area etc), but you get the gist.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm comfortable with the C# language, it's just the arrangement and configuration that has me a bit stumped.

I realise this question may seem somewhat ambiguous - please post comments and I'll try to clarify where necessary.

Thanks,

Neil.

Comment: How exactly do you plan on hosting this web service? Is it a SOAP service, a RESTful service or some custom http handler?

Comment: @Doobi the app will be distributed to my customers, and they will be hosting it however they like - from shared hosting to dedicated servers. It's a custom HTTP handler, effectively encapsulated REST which is always POSTed to a single endpoint.

Comment: The error message you've provided: is this all you're seeing? Nothing else is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed. I had to turn the folder into an application in IIS, and move the source to a trusted (non-network) location.

My gratitude for those who took the time to review this question.

Answer (score 1):

What does the EventLog say ? There probably should be a record (of type "Warning" with the source which looks like "ASP.NET x.x.xxxxx.x").

Anyway, you mentioned in the beginning of your post that you'd like to have a single DLL-file (among with the web.config) to be distributed. Later you point to the `.ashx` file.

I'd rather create a single class (.cs file within your project) and put the implementation of my HTTP handler in that class.

Also, double-check that the type of your HTTP handler is specified correctly in a web.config:

```
<add verb="*" path="*" type="[namespace].[type], [assembly]" />
```

If you're using IIS6 then you need to manually add a wildcard script mapping in order for your HTTP handler to "catch" the requests. [This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1371470.aspx) forum post might help.

-- Pavel

Comment: Thanks Pavel. To clarify, a `.ashx` file is what I have at the moment. I don't really care if it stays that way; ultimately I need a small number of files that can be FTPed to shared hosting with no additional configuration (eg registering DLLs in IIS etc). And yeah, the `type` attribute is correct :)